# creating 512 partitioned tables with loop for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am creating a table which would have 512 partitions in PostgreSQL 12. The table will be partitioned using hashing.

How can I create the 512 partitions without having to create each one manually?

Would creating a loop using pl/pgsql would be the best route?

```
create table dept_1 partition of dept FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 512, REMAINDER 0);
create table dept_2 partition of dept FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 512, REMAINDER 1);
create table dept_3 partition of dept FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 512, REMAINDER 2);
......
create table dept_512 partition of dept FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 512, REMAINDER 511);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use plpgsql inside `DO` command

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 0..511
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('create table %I partition of dept for values with (modulus 512, remainder %s)', 'depth_' || i + 1, i);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: thanks, works good, but there is a missing ")" after "(modulus 512, remainder %s"